# How to access specific elements in an array in maxima?

Tags: maxima

After using the solve command to solve two simultaneous non linear equations, I am getting an array of `x` and `y` and I need to access specific elements in this array.

```
A: 0.500000000000000$
B: 0.709506070053745$
C: 0.242527534593605$
D: 0.719012140107490$
E: 0.357164044380080$
F:-0.505315948652670$
G: 0.181895650945204$
H: 0.300000000000000$  

solve([
    x^2*(A*y^3+B*y-C)-D*x*y^2+E*y^3,
    A*x^2+(x/y^2)*(H*y+G)+F
    ] ,[x,y]),numer;
```

Here, `x` and `y` contain 8 values each and I need to access say only the 2nd element.

Answer (score 2):

Maxima returns a list of results here (a maxima array is something slightly different). Each element of the list is a pair of equations (x = ... and y = ...). For others reading this, the results look like

```
 [[x = .06111426947129051, y = .1679154401926679], 
  [x = - 6.026109660574413, y = .3056091599125177], 
  [x = .2909171173159695, y = .4452108480953128], 
  [x = .4561445354339108 %i + 1.180400961416986, 
   y = .8695950265919334 %i + .05136082885038127], 
  [x = 1.180400961416985 - .4561445354339104 %i, 
   y = .05136082885038127 - .8695950265919334 %i], 
  [x = .06097600174281474 %i - 0.77772869099467, 
   y = 0.792517152411182 %i - .5107285531053073], 
  [x = - .06097600174281463 %i - 0.77772869099467, 
   y = - 0.792517152411182 %i - .5107285531053073],
  [x = 0, y = 0]]
```

Now, I'm not sure from your question whether you want just each `y` coordinate, or whether you want the second solution that solve found. For the second solution, just use `[n]` to get the n'th thing. So if I stored the list above as the variable `solns`, I could use

```
(%i12) solns[2];
(%o12)         [x = - 6.026109660574413, y = .3056091599125177]
```

If you want each `y` coordinate, you have to map into the list. For example, try this:

```
(%i14) map(lambda([pair], rhs(second(pair))), solns);
(%o14) [.1679154401926679,
        .3056091599125177,
        .4452108480953128, 
        .8695950265919334 %i + .05136082885038127,
        .05136082885038127 - .8695950265919334 %i, 
        0.792517152411182 %i - .5107285531053073, 
        - 0.792517152411182 %i - .5107285531053073,
        0]
```

(I tidied up the formatting of the output slightly). Or you could equally do

```
map(rhs, map(second, solns));
```

which gives exactly the same answer but without needing to write a lambda form.